# jQuery mouseenter event is not executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm having some trouble with **mouseenter event** applied on div area in my pages. I'm trying to change background-color of this div on mouse enter but it is all just ignored.

I have a simple HTML CODE:

```
<div id="services" class="services">
  <div id="services-top">
    <h2>Services</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="services-content">
    <div id="services-content-left">
      <img id="services-content-right-img" class="img-circle" src="http://i.imgur.com/vN5m4vK.jpg" alt="empty">
      <h3>STUFF</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And JS stuff with this event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("services-content-left").mouseenter(function() {
    console.log("enter");
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
  });
});
```

And as I said before, when I enter this div area, background stays the same, without any changes.
[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/m2wpetp4/3/) is an example.
Don't you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Typo `$("services-content-left")` looks for an element tag `<services-content-left>`, you need the pound sign `#` to identify the selector as an ID selector `$("#services-content-left")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply missed out

## out in your code, should be  $("#services-content-left") instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#services-content-left").mouseenter(function() {
        console.log("enter");
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
});
```

## signify a ID selector.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong selector :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#services-content-left").mouseenter(function() {
    console.log("enter");
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a `#` before your **services-content-left**,

Please have it changed as,

`$("#services-content-left").mouseenter(function() {`

**Working Fiddle:** - https://jsfiddle.net/m2wpetp4/4/

Hope this helps!